Swap colors of 2 faces on a cube using an interactive button or keypress
I'm looking to make an interactive environment where I can press either a virtual button on screen, or a keypress - for example letter A - and it swaps the colors of 2 faces on a cube.
I believe using UPBGE is the only way to make an interactive environment, just checking on this methodology. Perhaps this function can be accomplished with the python scripting?
I'm thinking this color swapping function can be done using the logic node editor in UPGBE - and that would stupendous! I am getting stuck on this part: how do I grab the colored material of face1 and assign it to the color of face2, then take face2's color and assign it to face1's original color?
If this is not possible in logic node editor, then how would I accomplish this with python code? Also, if it helps making each face of a cube a separate object, that's fine too (probably not necessary for the experts out there).
Thanks in advance!
P.S. the closest UPBGE solution I found was this thread, however the color is applied to the entire object, no color swapping function.
